What is the difference between "packet drops" from "ip -s link" and "socket drops" from "ss -tm"?
ss -tm shows detailed memory information about each TCP session. I found that some of the tcp sessions show sock_drop, here is one:
ESTAB    ***** some irrelevant info here ****               
     skmem:(r0,rb3446699,t0,tb87040,f0,w0,o0,bl0,d222)  

d222 in skmem, according the the man page, is the sock_drop number.
But ip -s link (or ifconfig) both shows 0 packet drops
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:d9:fb:52 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX:   bytes   packets errors dropped  missed   mcast           
    79371129016 110948258      0       0       0       0 
    TX:   bytes   packets errors dropped carrier collsns           
    78030205763  96204113      0       0       0       0 

So here is my question: What is the difference between packet drops showed in ip -s link and sock_drop showed in ss -tm? What are the possible reasons that causes packet drop and sock_drop? Is sock_drop related to tcp retransmission?

Not going to answer because I dont know for sure, but "packet drops" might represent packets that arrived at an adapter level but weren't taken off the ring buffer in time by the kernel (too many packets per second arriving). Whereas "socket drops" could be where the individual socket buffer had more data in it than was being consumed by the application so some new data that has arrived was discarded.

The dropped counter in ip -s is an OS-wide counter for ethernet frames dropped by the kernel because of things like CRC + checksum errors. Also other things like failed IP fragment re-assemblies.
The d222 counter there is a per-socket counter. Try ss -pntm to see the process that owns it. What this means is that the OS tried to deliver a packet to a userspace program and failed because the receive buffer (rb3446699) was full. This usually suggests that the software wasn't able to read from it quickly enough. The r0 shows that it was empty at the time you ran ss so perhaps a transient error? These per-socket drops don't show in ip -s.
Increasing the rmem_max and rmem_default values in sysctl can help software ride over such transient errors, but there's a trade-off in memory usage (If you serve a lot of connections) and latency.
NB: If you run nstat you can see a list of more specific OS counters, some of which are sum totals of socket-level errors such as these for UDP and TCP.

Thank you very much for your answer. Really appreciated!

No worries. Please accept the answer if it covers everything you need. (It helps promote it for other searchers)
